# svn external path on a versioned directory

Tags: svn, svn-externals

Say I have the following structure (on the same svn server, but different repos):

```
Repo:
A/
A/B/c.py

External Project:
C/D/
C/B/f.py
```

I want to set svn:externals on A/, like so:

```
^/../C/D A/D
^/../C/B A/B
```

My goal is to have the resulting structure look like this:

```
A/
A/D
A/B/c.py
A/B/f.py
```

After I do propset on A/ (and double check it with propget), I run "svn up A/". svn fetches C/D/ just fine, but when fetching C/B/, it says that B/ is locked. Is it possible to do this, or does svn not support mixing an external directory with a local svn directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not possible. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html where it says:

> The relative target subdirectories of externals definitions *must not* already exist on your or other users' systems

Comment: so basically, the target folder of the external source cannot already exist (and therefore cannot be a versioned folder)?

Comment: Exactly. Or at least, the last folder in the path you give as a target cannot already exist; you can place it any number of existing folders deep, but the last folder must not already exist.